# How can I send a file wirelessly without bluetooth or a Wi-Fi network in ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, file-transfer, vanilla-android

I know that one of the new features is [WiFi-direct](http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/) for ICS (noted at the very bottom of the page in the link).  Is there a way to leverage this new feature to transmit files from one ICS device to another?

This would be useful because the WiFi speeds would be greater than bluetooth, and you wouldn't need to be connected to a WiFi network or create a hotspot.

The Samsung Galaxy S II apparently has this feature [built in](http://androidadvices.com/galaxy-s2-wifi-direct-feature-high-speed-data-transfer/) pre-ICS (go Samsung!). Is this same method available in ICS? Or is there an app for it?

**EDIT:**  Because the galaxy nexus is made by Samsung, and is the only device out with ICS right now, I'm not sure if this "WiFi Direct" sharing (per the link and Ryan's answer below) is built in to ICS vanilla (Samsung did have WiFi Direct sharing pre-ICS, after all).

As such, I've added a vanilla tag, so I'm asking, **is in the vanilla source code to allow a way for users to share files using WiFi Direct?  If not, is there an app for it in the market?**  I want to know how to do this on all ICS phones, not necessarily just the galaxy nexus.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Android 4.0 introduces [WiFi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) in to the core of android. it basically creates an adhoc connection between one device and another using WiFi by creating what I guess could be considered an Access Point. You do not need a wifi access point to use WiFi Direct, and actually, if you are connected to wifi when turning on WiFi direct, it will disconnect you. You cannot be connected to both an Access Point and enable wifi direct.

The host device acts as an access point for other devices to connect to, then through other pieces of software, files and other data can be shared or streamed to the client device(s).

To use Wifi Direct, in `settings -> wireless & networks` you have to enable it. Then you should have an option to "share" via wifi. This works a lot like bluetooth sharing, where the other device has to be "ready to accept" your files. You will only be able to do wifi direct with devices that have explicit support for wifi direct. Android 4.0 is the the first version of the OS to have built in support for wifi direct. The Samsung Galaxy S II does have support for wifi direct as well. This was an added feature Samsung put in to their TouchWiz version of Android. While the settings for it are a little different then in Android 4.0, they basically work the same.

There are other devices, like some TVs by Sony, that also have wifi direct support.

Wifi Direct is not hardware specific, its part of the OS. If the device supports wifi then it supports this. It is part of the CORE OS in Android 4.0. Any device that has Wifi and is running ICS, this will work with. Some Samsung devices (I think only the Galaxy S 2) have support for wifi direct even though they are not running ICS. This is because Samsung added the support for it in to their version of Android.

While the Galaxy Nexus is manufactured by Samsung, it does not run the Samsung modified version of Android. It runs a completely "Google Experience" version of Android. The WiFi direct that exists on the Samsung Galaxy S II is different then the one built in to Android 4.0.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html) is the android SDK docs that talks about support.

> Wi-Fi Direct allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each other via Wi-Fi without an intermediate access point. Using these APIs, you can discover and connect to other devices when each device supports Wi-Fi Direct, then communicate over a speedy connection across distances much longer than a Bluetooth connection. This is useful for applications that share data among users, such as a multiplayer game or a photo sharing application.

Here is a screen shot (taken from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=enEBelknmBQ#t=89s)) showing wifi direct setting available on a Nook Color running CM9. The video is at the location where it shows wifi direct working.
[image: nook color/cm9/wifi direct]

[image: another shot]

Here are 2 screenshots from my viewsonic g-tablet that is running ICS (this is not a CM9 Kang, it is vanilla AOSP android). The first shows the setting, the second shows that i turned it on.
[image]
[image]

To show that WiFi Direct is actually part of the core of android and not just CM9, here is the source code for the [WiFi direct settings](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/master/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p). This is the github mirror of the AOSP. You can compare it to [CM9 source](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/tree/ics/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p) too.

Comment: Just a heads up -- I edited the question to directly ask how to transfer files with Wi-Fi Direct.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to hopefully explain how to use wifi direct.

Comment: I can't find anything like "Wifi Direct" under settings -> wireless & networks.

Comment: @offby1 are you using an emulator?  I looked in my friend's galaxy nexus and the setting was there.  Come to think of it now though... it is a samsung device.

Comment: @RyanConrad can you provide a source showing that this will work on all ICS phones?  I've updated my question.

Comment: @John i modified my answer to cover your last comment.

Comment: It is a part of ICS and not only Gnex...

Comment: I added screenshots of wifi direct working on a viewsonic gtablet that is running ICS.

Comment: @RyanConrad, while the information you've added is related to WiFi Direct, it still doesn't fully answer the question... having WiFi direct in the API doesn't necessarily mean it is available as a feature of the OS settings, and while it is present on CM9, CyanogenMod is still a ROM, and it is possible the feature was incorporated... unless you can show that CM9 used the vanilla android settings source code?  Also the gtablet is also running a ROM, I believe it's native OS was 2.2.

Comment: my tablet is not running CM9, it is running VANILLA AOSP android. But here is the [cyanogen code](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/tree/ics/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p) and here is the [android code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/master/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p). They are the same.

Comment: @RyanConrad do you have a reference for saying that WiFi Direct is not hardware dependent? The Nexus S running vanilla ICS does not have that feature enabled. The Motorola Xoom on vanilla ICS does not have that feature either. The code might be there, but I'm pretty sure there's some kind of hardware dependence, or all ICS devices would have it.

Comment: @RyanConrad thanks, that answers my question :)  I'd be interested to know the answer to davidbb's comment too, but it's not my question.

Comment: Answering the above question: no, I'm not running an emulator; I have a Nexus S with stock Android 4.0.3, and there is no "Wi-fi direct" menu item anywhere.

Comment: I have Nexus S running CM9. I don't have it either. I think I read from somewhere it is hardware dependent after all. (Most of the newer phones have this though)

Comment: Yes, it is hardware dependent, to an extent. Most recent devices have wifi chips that support it, in my post I do initially say that it is not, but later I quote the docs that say that it is.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on _Then you should have an option to "share" via wifi._ ? Where should this option be?

Answer (score 3):

There's a new app on the Android market called FileBeam that lets you Beam DropBox files from Android to Android. Maybe that can help you too ;)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.filebeamapp.android

Comment: The link is eventually dead. An update is required here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reference to the feature in the source code, but with a different name: WifiP2P. Just did a search in GrepCode and found the package [android.net.wiki.p2p](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/p2p/).

Wifi Direct itself is located in [com.example.android.wifidirect](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/wifidirect/), so I don't think it's necessarily included in vanilla OSs, this is just an example on how to use the Wifi P2P API. Someone with more experience in Android source may know better.

Comment: it is included in vanilla android. I have ICS installed on my viewsonic gtablet and tried it with a friend that has the galaxy nexus. The like to wifidirect you posted is the example code on how other applications can integrate with the protocol to launch the intents that are part of the OS.

Answer (score -3):

For Samsung G-Note users (possibly SII and SIII users too), go to Settings, then under the Wireless and Networks section select More..., and you will see the option there.

Comment: The question is about stock ICS, and it's not about whether you can turn WiFi-Direct on, but if you can use it for file sharing.