# How to transfer files using WiFi Direct between 2 ICS devices?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, file-transfer, wifi-direct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to send a file wirelessly without bluetooth or a wifi network in ICS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19985/is-it-possible-to-send-a-file-wirelessly-without-bluetooth-or-a-wifi-network-in)

I recently asked the question whether it was *possible* to transfer 2 files between two ICS devices [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19985/is-it-possible-to-send-a-file-wirelessly-without-bluetooth-or-a-wifi-network-in/19986#19986).

This leads to the question:  **How do I transfer files between two ICS-devices using WiFi Direct?**  Is there a way to do it built-in to ICS, or is there an app for it?

**UPDATE:**

The Samsung Galaxy S II apparently has this feature [built in](http://androidadvices.com/galaxy-s2-wifi-direct-feature-high-speed-data-transfer/) pre-ICS (go samsung!). Is this same method available in ICS?

Comment: I really don't think these should be separate questions.  I'm going to edit the other to ask this.