# WiFi Direct Doesn't Work

Tags: nexus-7, file-transfer, motorola-droid-razr, wifi-direct

I have two Android devices running Android 4.1.1 with the latest OTA update from the manufacturer. I do not have root or any other system-level customizations on either device, just a bunch of very standard apps.

Device 1: Google Nexus 7

Device 2: Motorola Droid Razr Maxx HD

The *only* way I have found to send a file between these two devices, without the involvement of a third device (router, computer, SD card, ...) is using the Bluetooth file beaming protocol, which is incredibly slow and short-range. I wanted to use WiFi Direct to achieve much greater speed and distance for file transfers, but I can't get WiFi Direct to connect.

I followed all the instructions and read all the comments [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19986/17418) but it just doesn't work.

On this screen, I can see the other Android device advertising WiFi Direct:

[image: wifi-direct]

What I **can't** seem to do is to get them to connect to each other. I see the request go to the other device, and receive the request pop-up asking me to confirm the connection. I click Accept, and then after a few seconds, the UI on both devices "resets" to the first screen (the screenshot above) with no indication that a connection was successful.

Side-note: NFC doesn't work either and exhibits similar symptoms of the devices "just not being compatible". It's 2013 and I can hold two flagship Android devices right next to eachother and have *no* way to send files between them any faster than about 100 KB/s bluetooth beaming.

Comment: What version of Android and what ROMs are you running on your devices?

Comment: It's Android 4.1.1 on both devices. They are stock, OTA ROMs as I said. Both devices have received multiple OTA updates from the respective manufacturers over time, but I've never rooted or installed custom ROMs.

Comment: Sorry I just assumed based on the Screen shot that your Nexus 7 was running some CyanogenMod variant as that screenshot is not stock. I now realize that you posted it from the other post. Can you include screenshots of what you actually see?

Comment: That screenshot is copied from the post I linked to in my question. That isn't from my actual system. Sorry for the confusion.